# .xls file can be imported but not the .xlsx into MYSQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, excel

The below is the code which i tried for importing file(excel/csv) into MYSQL Database using php. This imports only the files with .xls extension and not .xlsx 
May i know whats the mess with the code, either we have to include any library into the code or any change should be made.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <?php 
 include 'connect.php';
 include 'Excel/reader.php';
 function uploadFile($fieldName, $fileType, $folderName, $name = "")
 {
    $flg = 0;
    $MaxID = "";
    $ext = "";
    $uploadfile = "";
    if (isset($fieldName) AND $fieldName['name'] != '')
    {
        $flg = 1;
        $allowed_filetypes = $fileType;
        $max_filesize = 1048576;
        $filename = $fieldName['name'];
        if ($name == "")
            $MaxID = time() . time() . rand(1, 100);
        else
            $MaxID = $name;
        $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename, '.'), strlen($filename) - 1);
  if($ext==".xlsx")
$ext=".xlsx";
        if (!in_array($ext, $allowed_filetypes))
            echo "<h1>The file you attempted to upload is not allowed...</h1>";
        else if (filesize($fieldName['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
            echo "<h1>The file you attempted to upload is too large...</h1>";
        else 
        {
            $uploadfile = $folderName . "/" . $MaxID . $ext;
            if (move_uploaded_file($fieldName['tmp_name'], $uploadfile) == FALSE)
            {
                echo "<h1>Error in Uploading File...</h1>";
                $MaxID = "";
            }
            else
                $MaxID = $MaxID . $ext;
        }
    }
    return $MaxID;
  }
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
 if($_FILES['csvFile']['name']!="")
 {
 $fileName=uploadFile($_FILES['excelFile'],array(".csv"),"excel_file");
 $row=0;
 if(($handle = fopen("test.csv".$fileName , "r")) !== FALSE) 
 {
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
 {
 $num = count($data);
 //print_r($data);
 $query="INSERT INTO  dealer_tbl(firstname,lastname,email,phone)VALUES('".$data[0]."','".$data[1]."','".$data[2]."','".$data[3]."')";
 mysql_query($query);
}
fclose($handle);
}
}
else if($_FILES['excelFile']['name']!="")
{
$fileName=uploadFile($_FILES['excelFile'],array(".xls",".xlsx"),"excel_file");
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();

$data->read('excel_file/'.$fileName);

for($i=1;$i<=$data->sheets[0]['numRows'];$i++)
{ $title=$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][1];
$firstname=$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][2];
$lastname=$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][3];
$mobile=$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][4];
$phone=$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][5];
echo $firstname."','".$lastname."','".$mobile."','".$phone;
$query="INSERT INTO  dealer_tbl(title,firstname,lastname,email,phone)VALUES('".$title."','".$firstname."','".$lastname."','".$mobile."','".$phone."')";
mysql_query($query);
}
}
}
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{
mysql_query("DELETE FROM StudentData");
}
?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="master_net_effect.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-custom.css">


<!-- HTML5 Shim, for IE6-IE8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->


    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-38395785-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async =  true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') +  '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
 </script>

 </head>
 <body>    

 <!-- Navbar
 ================================================== -->


<div id="header"> <a id="con_logo_link" href="http://s672.t.en25.com/e/er?s=672& lid=3261&elq=00000000000000000000000000000000" target="_blank"><!-- logo --></a></div>
<div id="wrap">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="span6" id="form-login">
<form class="form-horizontal well" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="upload_excel" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <fieldset>
  <legend>Import Dealers List</legend>
  <div class="control-group">
   <div class="control-label">
    <label>Select CSV File</label>
   </div>
   <div class="controls">
    <input type="file" name="csvFile" class="input-large">
   </div>
  </div>
  or
  <div class="control-group">
   <div class="control-label">
    <label>Select Excel File</label>
   </div>
   <div class="controls">
    <input type="file" name="excelFile" class="input-large">
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
   <div class="controls">
   <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" data-loading-text="Loading...">Upload</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
<div class="span3 hidden-phone"></div>
</div>
<form name="del" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<div class="control-group">
<div class="controls">
 <button type="submit" id="delete" name="delete"  data-loading-text="Loading...">Delete Data</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
<th>Title</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Mobile</th>
<th>Phone</th>
</tr>
<?php
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dealer_tbl");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
?>
 <tr>
  <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['phone']; ?&gt..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader` class certainly reads only `XLS` file.

If you want to read `XLSX`, try [PhpExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com). This library can be extremely powerful.

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'Classes/');
include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$inputFileName = 'your_file_to_import.xlsx';
try {
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file :' . $e->getMessage());
}

$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
print_r($sheetData);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this it work for me: https://github.com/abdo0147/x2m this can read your xlsx file and give you a php file that will insert exel data to mysql and will give you a file to test if your data was inserted correctly.